# Problemas para instalar o Composer no Windows

Tags: php, windows, composer

Estou tentando instalar o Composer por [esse tutorial](http://tableless.com.br/composer-para-iniciantes/) no Windows, mas estou com problemas na hora de baixar tanto pelo PHP como pelo cURL.

[image: Screenshot do erro]

Comment: primeiro voce tem que instalar o curl [atraves do site oficial](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Comment: Voce pode instalar pelo php na sua segunda opção, porem voce deve ver se o php e versão 5.3 ou posterior usando php --version, quando voce executou o comando de instalação pelo php ocorreu um erro de syntax, copia todo o comando e cole la e execute: php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php

Comment: Cara, por que você não baixa o instalador normal?

Answer (score 2):

Tente instalar pelo próprio instalador oferecido pela Composer, [Composer-Setup.exe](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe). Boa sorte!